# What types of bus couplers exist?

Tags: high-voltage, power-engineering

There are various types of bus couplers (for double bus system, single section bus system, etc.).

I know that bus coupler between two busbars is called cross bus coupler.

How are other bus couplers called, how do we divide them by type?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A bus coupler is just a normal circuit breaker (and isolators), no matter where it's installed, or which busses it's connecting.

A "cross bus coupler" is just a bus coupler that happens to be connecting the two busses of a double-bus switchyard. It's not a different type of switchgear and shouldn't be classified as such.

---

Similar terms are:

- Bus tie
- Bus section (circuit breaker) - in switchboards